# Is it possible to write xml schema to validate both text node and element node in root element?

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like both of two be valid.

```
<a>
 <b></b>
</a>
```

or

```
<a>My text</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `mixed=true` attribute when you define complexType for `a`. See details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp)

Example:

```
<xs:element name="a">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: You'll need to make the b element optional as well, using minOccurs.